# optimization of a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I do to optimize this request? The processing time is very long.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT  CONCAT(p.sku,'_IM') as REF, CONCAT(p.ref_fabriq,' / FR ',COALESCE(frtemp.dispo,0),' - EU ',COALESCE(eutemp.dispo,0),' / CDE : FR ',COALESCE(frtemp.command,0),' - EU ',COALESCE(eutemp.command,0),' / ETA : FR ',COALESCE(frtemp.eta,''),' - EU ',COALESCE(eutemp.eta,''),'/ DATE FP : ',p.fin_promo,' / ',p.class_prod,' / ',p.crc) AS DESCRIPTION
FROM price as p
LEFT JOIN totfrhrl_temp frtemp ON p.sku = frtemp.sku
LEFT JOIN totrihrl_temp eutemp ON p.sku = eutemp.sku

WHERE p.sku IN (SELECT ALL fr.sku FROM totfrhrl as fr LEFT JOIN totfrhrl_temp frtemp ON fr.sku = frtemp.sku LEFT JOIN totrihrl_temp eutemp ON fr.sku = eutemp.sku WHERE fr.dispo != frtemp.dispo OR fr.command != frtemp.command OR fr.eta != frtemp.eta UNION SELECT ALL eu.sku FROM totrihrl as eu LEFT JOIN totrihrl_temp eutemp ON eu.sku = eutemp.sku LEFT JOIN totfrhrl_temp frtemp ON eu.sku = frtemp.sku WHERE eu.dispo != eutemp.dispo OR eu.command != eutemp.command OR eu.eta != eutemp.eta)
```

Comment: How long is "very long", exactly?  Details like this help folks figure out what sorts of optimizations will work for your needs.

Comment: exemple : 8032 total, Query took 70.1244 seconds

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure if this works but it should be another way to get your result. since i don't know the index or any other information about your tables what i do is change your left join and make **union** to **union all** while add some code to do the cut duplicate part.

```
SELECT ALL fr.sku, fr.dispo, eutemp.dispo 
  FROM totfrhrl as fr 
LEFT JOIN totrihrl_temp eutemp ON fr.sku = eutemp.sku 
WHERE exists(select 1 from totfrhrl_temp frtemp 
       where frtemp.sku = fr.sku 
       and ( fr.dispo != frtemp.dispo OR fr.command != frtemp.command OR fr.eta != frtemp.eta))

Union ALL

SELECT ALL eu.sku, eu.dispo, frtemp.dispo 
  FROM totrihrl as eu 
LEFT JOIN totfrhrl_temp frtemp ON eu.sku = frtemp.sku 
WHERE exists(select 1 from totrihrl_temp eutemp 
       where eutemp.sku = eu.sku
         and (eu.dispo != eutemp.dispo OR eu.command != eutemp.command OR eu.eta != eutemp.eta))
and not exists (select 1 from totfrhrl as fr  where fr.sku=eu.sku)
```

it will works if sku is a key to your table

Comment: @FAPM i tried to fix some problem might cost the empty result, please try again.

Comment: 8032 total, Query took 70.1244 seconds :)

Answer (score -1):

I tested it with :)
It's good for :

```
SELECT ALL p.sku, CONCAT(p.sku,frtemp.dispo,frtemp.command,frtemp.eta,eutemp.dispo,eutemp.command,eutemp.eta) as new, CONCAT(p.sku,fr.dispo,fr.command,fr.eta,eu.dispo,eu.command,eu.eta)

FROM price as p

LEFT JOIN totfrhrl_temp frtemp ON p.sku = frtemp.sku
LEFT JOIN totrihrl_temp eutemp ON p.sku = eutemp.sku
LEFT JOIN totfrhrl fr ON p.sku = fr.sku
LEFT JOIN totrihrl eu ON p.sku = eu.sku

WHERE CONCAT(p.sku,frtemp.dispo,frtemp.command,frtemp.eta,eutemp.dispo,eutemp.command,eutemp.eta) != CONCAT(p.sku,fr.dispo,fr.command,fr.eta,eu.dispo,eu.command,eu.eta)
```

Are there opportunities to improve this ? :)

Comment: 205 seconds for 5300 rows :/